# rails_admin datepicker not letting me set a b.c. date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, rails-admin

I have a datetime column in my postgres db. rails_admin was working fine with it until I tried to set a date b.c.

The date picker allows me to go back to negative dates. However, as soon as I leave the field, it removes the '-'. I tried editing it by hand, but it does the same thing. e.g. 'January 04, -3761 00:00' becomes 'January 04, 3761 00:00'

I can think of several possible solutions:

- I think the preferred solution for me would be to use a different datepicker. This one is kind of annoying, especially with time. I have bootstrap. Any way to do this?
- Disable the datepicker, somehow, and type it in by hand. If this is the solution, I would rather type in a number format as in '2018/01/01' instead of 'January 1, 2018' This solution would be fine as well, but I could not figure out how to do this.
- I could change the column type from datetime to plain text and parse it myself, but I would much rather not do this.

As an aside, perhaps datetime is not the best way to store these kinds of dates?

rails_admin 1.4.1
rails 5.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do the second solution referred to above. I needed to make a template. As described in the [docs for rails admin](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Fields). See Form Rendering.

My model now looks something like this:

```
rails_admin do
  field :date_x do
    ...
    strftime_format '%Y-%m-%d'
    partial 'date_partial.html.haml'
    ...
  end
end
```

And the partial (app/views/rails_admin/main/_date_partial.html.haml)

```
= form.text_field field.method_name, field.html_attributes.reverse_merge({ value: field.form_value, class: 'form-control' })
```